# Power steering seems to cutout whilst stationary.

Tags: ford, focus, power-steering

Ford focus 2009 (UK) Power steering seems to cutout whilst stationary and kick back in when moving. Is this normal. Power fluid is black/dirty. Garage changed fluid but only 'sucked out reservoir and topped up'. This improved feel temporarily but no change to cutting out at standstill. Could dirty fluid indicate wearing/broken parts? Thanks

Comment: When at standstill, if you rev the motor does it help?

Comment: No the power steering seems to go off after about 5 seconds then when i touch the steering wheel there is a slight woosh as if to take up air and its back on. There is no loss of fluid at all.It's almost a power save mode if it has one!

Comment: If it has an electric power steering pump this may be normal. How long has it been doing this?

Comment: Since i've owned the car - 2yrs now. Wondered if it is causing fluid to contaminate or not. Is this common with electric ps then?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that your power steering pump is done or it might be the entire rack-and-pinion is shot as well. Power steering should be happening now at a stand still, not when you are moving. In fact, while you are moving, it may feel there is power steering because the wheels will move left to right and back much easier without the assist of power steering. It could be that the valve in the R&P which tells the fluid to assist is bad. If so, it won't divert the hydraulic fluid as needed to make the assist possible.